# Why is my counter always equal to zero even after the correct radio button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

In my Javascript code, I increment the counter when the right radio button is checked but when I check in the console, the counter doesn't get updated after the correct radio button is checked. Even after I click the submit button which calls a function clicked() that displays the counter. The counter still remains zero. Is there a reason why it doesn't get updated. Here is my Java Script code:

```js
var counter = 0;

if (document.getElementById('blue').checked) {
  counter++;
}

if (document.getElementById('age3').checked) {
  counter++;
}

if (document.getElementById('hobby2').checked) {
  counter++;
}

if (document.getElementById('game3').checked) {
  counter++;
}

if (document.getElementById('language4').checked) {
  counter++;
}

function clicked() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You got " + counter;
}
```

```html
<h1>Quiz</h1>

<form>
  <p>(1) What is my favourite Color?</p>
  <input type="radio" id="blue" name="color" value="blue">
  <label for="blue">blue</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="red" name="color" value="red">
  <label for="red">red</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="green" name="color" value="green">
  <label for="green">green</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="purple" name="color" value="purple">
  <label for="purple">purple</label>

  <br>

  <p>(2) How Old am I?</p>
  <input type="radio" id="age1" name="age" value="20">
  <label for="age1">20</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="age2" name="age" value="22">
  <label for="age2">22</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="age3" name="age" value="21">
  <label for="age3">21</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="age4" name="age" value="23">
  <label for="age4">23</label>

  <br>

  <p>(3) Which of the following is not of a hobby of mine?</p>
  <input type="radio" id="hobby1" name="hobby" value="swimming">
  <label for="hobby1">swimming</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="hobby2" name="hobby" value="soccer">
  <label for="hobby2">soccer</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="hobby3" name="hobby" value="chess">
  <label for="hobby3">chess</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="hobby4" name="hobby" value="coding">
  <label for="hobby4">coding</label>

  <br>

  <p>(4) Which of the following is a game that I like?</p>
  <input type="radio" id="game1" name="game" value="NBA">
  <label for="game1">NBA</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="game2" name="game" value="FortNite">
  <label for="game2">FortNite</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="game3" name="game" value="God of War">
  <label for="game3">God of War</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="game4" name="game" value="Call of Duty">
  <label for="game4">Call of Duty</label>

  <p>(5) At what is my favourite language</p>
  <input type="radio" id="language1" name="language" value="python">
  <label for="language1">python</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="language2" name="language" value="Javascript">
  <label for="language2">Javascript</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="language3" name="language" value="C++">
  <label for="language3">C++</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="language4" name="language" value="Java">
  <label for="language4">Java</label><br><br>



</form>

<button onclick="clicked()">Submit</button>

<p id="result"> </p>
```

Comment: That's because you're checking all the radio buttons at the very beginning. None is checked, so the total is 0. Then the game is displayed and starts. Clicking the radio buttons does nothing because they have no click event listener attached to them. At the end, you click the button, which displays 0 because nothing happened in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all those radio button checkings into a function and call that function when you hit submit. This should solve your problem.

```js
var counter = 0;
function updateCounter(){

if (document.getElementById('blue').checked) {
  counter++;
}

if (document.getElementById('age3').checked) {
  counter++;
}

if (document.getElementById('hobby2').checked) {
  counter++;
}

if (document.getElementById('game3').checked) {
  counter++;
}

if (document.getElementById('language4').checked) {
  counter++;
}
}

function clicked() {
  updateCounter()
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You got " + counter;
  //reset the counter back to zero after displaying score
  counter = 0
}
```

```html
<h1>Quiz</h1>

<form>
  <p>(1) What is my favourite Color?</p>
  <input type="radio" id="blue" name="color" value="blue">
  <label for="blue">blue</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="red" name="color" value="red">
  <label for="red">red</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="green" name="color" value="green">
  <label for="green">green</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="purple" name="color" value="purple">
  <label for="purple">purple</label>

  <br>

  <p>(2) How Old am I?</p>
  <input type="radio" id="age1" name="age" value="20">
  <label for="age1">20</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="age2" name="age" value="22">
  <label for="age2">22</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="age3" name="age" value="21">
  <label for="age3">21</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="age4" name="age" value="23">
  <label for="age4">23</label>

  <br>

  <p>(3) Which of the following is not of a hobby of mine?</p>
  <input type="radio" id="hobby1" name="hobby" value="swimming">
  <label for="hobby1">swimming</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="hobby2" name="hobby" value="soccer">
  <label for="hobby2">soccer</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="hobby3" name="hobby" value="chess">
  <label for="hobby3">chess</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="hobby4" name="hobby" value="coding">
  <label for="hobby4">coding</label>

  <br>

  <p>(4) Which of the following is a game that I like?</p>
  <input type="radio" id="game1" name="game" value="NBA">
  <label for="game1">NBA</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="game2" name="game" value="FortNite">
  <label for="game2">FortNite</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="game3" name="game" value="God of War">
  <label for="game3">God of War</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="game4" name="game" value="Call of Duty">
  <label for="game4">Call of Duty</label>

  <p>(5) At what is my favourite language</p>
  <input type="radio" id="language1" name="language" value="python">
  <label for="language1">python</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="language2" name="language" value="Javascript">
  <label for="language2">Javascript</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="language3" name="language" value="C++">
  <label for="language3">C++</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="language4" name="language" value="Java">
  <label for="language4">Java</label><br><br>



</form>

<button onclick="clicked()">Submit</button>

<p id="result"> </p>
```

Comment: I'm too late. The answer above is correct.
See this:  https://codepen.io/krocon/pen/qBOLbjG

Answer (score 0):

Every time you are getting the value as 0 as the login you  written is not calling on clicking of radio button.

First thing Just defined the all radio button into a method like below.

```
 function SelectValue () {
     counter = 0;
if (document.getElementById('blue').checked)
{
    counter++;
}


if (document.getElementById('age3').checked)
{
    counter++;
}

if (document.getElementById('hobby2').checked)
{
    counter++;
}

if (document.getElementById('game3').checked)
{
    counter++;
}

if (document.getElementById('language4').checked)
{
    counter++;
}

}
```

Now there is two way you can call.

1. Either call that method in each and every method like below.

```
  <p>(1) What is my favourite Color?</p>
  <input type="radio" id="blue" name="color" value="blue" onclick="clickmethodthod()">
  <label for="blue">blue</label><br>
```

2. Write a logic of click and attached to all radio button.

```
let counter = 0;


const radios = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]');

for(radio in radios) {
    radios[radio].onclick = function() {
        SelectValue ()
    }
}
```

Let me know if you are getting any issue.